# VBA open workbook ignoring "missing library" error?

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently using the following code to open workbooks and search for particular strings:

```
    Set workbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(Path)

    Set VBProj = workbook.VBProject
    Set oComp = VBProj.VBComponents("Module1")

    Set CodeMod = oComp.CodeModule

    FindWhat = ToFindStr

    With CodeMod
        SL = 1
        EL = .CountOfLines
        SC = 1
        EC = 255
        Found = .Find(target:=FindWhat, StartLine:=SL, StartColumn:=SC, _
            EndLine:=EL, EndColumn:=EC, _
            wholeword:=True, MatchCase:=False, patternsearch:=False)
        Do Until Found = False
            Print #fnum1, "found"
            EL = .CountOfLines
            SC = EC + 1
            EC = 255
            Found = .Find(target:=FindWhat, StartLine:=SL, StartColumn:=SC, _
                EndLine:=EL, EndColumn:=EC, _
                wholeword:=True, MatchCase:=False, patternsearch:=False)
        Loop
    End With
```

The problem is there appears to be some compiler errors (missing library) when I open a couple of the spreadsheets. Is there any way I can get around this? I just need to get the CodeMod content to somewhere searchable- but the problem appears to be with opening the workbook.

Comment: What is the specific error you're getting?  Do you have any extra `References` that you've added that won't be persisting to this instance of Excel?

Comment: Its a missing library reference that my machine does not have.

Comment: To ignore errors, you can put `On Error GoTo 0` in the procedure in question to ignore errors.  [source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266173(v=vs.60).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the `Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility` reference added in order to run your code.

Tools > References > Then check it and click ok.

Comment: I have got this? I am saying the workbooks I am opening as part of my program require particular addins that my machine does not have. Therefore I need to open the file ignoring such errors (which i am guessing is impossible).